# Simple jQuery mouseover, mouseout, click script

Tags: jquery, click, mouseover, mouseout

I have 5 flags for 5 countries. If anyone mouseover the flags, a respective div will be shown. If mouseout, the div will hide. If the flag is clicked, then i want to keep the div visible and disable the mouseout event. The following coding makes everything okay, but when someone clicks on the flag, then the previous flags don't work but the next flags on click. If i click the last one flag first, then none of the previous flags work!!!

Please someone helps me.

Thanks for reading.

```
    <!-- popup UN -->
<div class="popup popup_hide popup_un" id="popup_un">
    <div class="popup_top"></div>
    <div class="popup_country">
        <img src="images/usa.gif" alt="USA">  
        <a href="#" class="hide_popup"><span class="close"></span></a>
        <div class="popup_country_text"> 
            <div class="popup_country_text_normal">  
            </div>
            <div class="btn_email_us"><a href="#"><img src="images/btn_email.jpg" alt="email us"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 


 <div id="footer_flag">
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_au"><img id="popup_au_img" src="images/au.gif" alt="AU"></a>
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_nz"><img id="popup_nz_img" src="images/nz.gif" alt="AU"></a>
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_uk"><img id="popup_uk_img" src="images/uk.png" alt="UK"></a>
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_canada"><img id="popup_canada_img" src="images/canada.png" alt="Canada"></a>
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_usa"><img id="popup_usa_img" src="images/usa.gif" alt="USA"></a>
<a href="#" class="showPopup showPopupClicked" rel="popup_un"><img id="popup_un_img" class="footer_flag_un" src="images/un.png" alt="UN"></a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.showPopup').mouseover( function() {
        $('.popup').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show()  
    });


    $('.showPopup').mouseout( function() {
        $('.popup_hide').hide(); 

    });             

    $('.hide_popup').click( function() {
        $('.popup').hide(); 
        $('img').removeClass('border_grey'); 

    });


    $('.showPopupClicked').click( function() {
        $('a').removeClass('showPopup');
        $('img').removeClass('border_grey');
        $('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).removeClass('popup_hide');
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').addClass('border_grey');

    }); 
});
```

]

Comment: $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show()  is wrong i think

Comment: Right .. I think he should replace `#` with `.` or viceversa

Comment: Fiddle for debugging http://jsfiddle.net/3Gj9T/

Comment: Hello Arun, I have added html

Comment: @ALL, the main problem here is I want to remove "showPopup" class when someone clicks on "showPopupClicked" so that the function of mousover does not work with "showPopup"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CODE:

```
var mouseOver = function() {
    //$('.popup').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
};

var mouseOut = function() {
    //$('.popup').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
};

$('.showPopup').mouseover(mouseOver);
$('.showPopup').mouseout(mouseOut);

$('.showPopup').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').removeClass('border_grey');
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).hide();
        $(this).removeClass("selected");

        $(this).bind("mouseover", mouseOver);
        $(this).bind("mouseout", mouseOut);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').addClass('border_grey');
        $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();

        $(this).unbind("mouseover", mouseOver);
        $(this).unbind("mouseout", mouseOut);
    }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Gj9T/9/)

Comment: Hello bhb,
Thanks for the code. Your code works nice but still showing one problem. If i click any flag, then code does not work wiht previous flags. If I click on the no 5 flag, flags 1-4 don't work.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Is it present in fiddle link(above).

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#' + $(this).attr('rel') + '_img').show()`

Also, nothing actually has class `.popup`, so I'm not sure what `$('.popup').hide();` accomplishes.